# Convert various length of List to Tuple in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I want convert list [[1,2,3],[2,3]] to tuple [(1,2,3),(2,3)]

my function:

```
thr [a,b,c] = (a,b,c)
tupel [] = []
tupel (x:xs) = if length x==3 then thr x:(tupel xs) else (tupel xs)
```

this work with three Elements.

```
thr [a,b,c] = (a,b,c)
two [a,b]   = (a,b)
tupel [] = []
tupel (x:xs) = if length x==3 then thr x:(tupel xs) else two x:(tupel xs)
```

why don´t work this?

Error: Type error in application
*** Expression     : two x : tupel2 xs**
 Term           : two x
 **Type           : (a,a)
*** Does not match : (a,a,a)

Comment: Pretty sure you'd need dependent types for something like this to actually work…

Comment: Dependent types are not necessary. This is just a plain old algebraic data type problem.

Comment: @Don Hmm, misread the question. The problem is that he wants a heterogeneous list.

Comment: Exactly, which are just regular lists with (explicit or implicit) tags.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, let's skip to the end and fire up ghci. What type does `[(1,2,3),(1,2)]` have?

```
ghci> :t [(1,2,3),(1,2)]

<interactive>:1:10:
     Couldn't match expected type `(t0, t1, t2)'
                 with actual type `(t3, t4)'
     In the expression: (1, 2)
     In the expression: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2)]
     In an equation for `it': it = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

That error isn't because I entered the data wrong, it's because `[(1,2,3),(1,2)]` isn't valid haskell.

A list in haskell can hold an unlimited number of items, with the caveat that all items must be of the same type.

It may seem weird, but `(1,2,3)` and `(1,2)` aren't of the same type.  One is a 3-tuple, one is a 2-tuple.

A tuple is sort of the opposite of a list - it can only hold a specific number of items, but they can be of a bunch of different types.  Tuple types are defined by the sequence of types given by the items they contain.

So a tuple of 3 integers (or, as ghc will show, number-like things) is of different type than a tuple of 2 integers.  We can see this directly using the `:t` operator in ghci:

```
ghci> :t (1,2,3)
(1,2,3) :: (Num t1, Num t2, Num t) => (t, t1, t2)
ghci> :t (1,2)
(1,2) :: (Num t1, Num t) => (t, t1)
```

See that `(2,3,4)` and `(2,3)` have types that match `(1,2,3)` and `(1,2)`'s respectively:

```
ghci> :t (2,3,4)
(2,3,4) :: (Num t1, Num t2, Num t) => (t, t1, t2)
ghci> :t (2,3)
(2,3) :: (Num t1, Num t) => (t, t1)
```

That's because `(2,3,4)` and `(1,2,3)` are two values that have the same type.  The same is true for `(1,2)` and `(2,3)`.

So there is no function to convert `[[1,2,3],[1,2]]` to `[(1,2,3),(1,2)]` in haskell because the result of such a function could not possibly type-check.

Answer (score 5):

Tuples have different types, so there's no single (simple) type to give to your `tupel` function.

However, by stepping back and using a *sum type* you can encode all the variants you wish to return:

```
data T a
    = One   a
    | Two   a a
    | Three a a a
    deriving Show

two :: [a] -> T a
two [a,b]   = Two   a b

thr :: [a] -> T a
thr [a,b,c] = Three a b c

tuple :: [[a]] -> [T a]
tuple []           = []
tuple ([a,b]  :xs) = Two   a b   : tuple xs
tuple ([a,b,c]:xs) = Three a b c : tuple xs
tuple (_ : xs)     =               tuple xs
```

Note how we distinguish between the two and three-element list case via pattern matching.

And secondly, it is good practice to write down your expected type for each function -- this will help resolve confusion in the design, and quickly reveal logical errors like the two different tuple types.

Running this, you can see how it groups things nicely:

```
*Main> tuple [[1,2,3],[2,3]] 
[Three 1 2 3,Two 2 3]
```

Comment: okay - nice thx, but how I convert [Three 1 2 3,Two 2 3] to [(1,2,3),(1,2)]? :D

Comment: @corium: It is not possible: lists in haskell are homogeneous (which mean that each element in the list has the same type as any other element) and tuples with different number of elements have different types.

Comment: is this possible func [1,2,3,4,5] --> to [(1,2,3),(4,5)] - the take n funktion take list, but i need tuple -.-

Comment: You **cannot** return a list of tuples, where the tuples have different sizes. You can however, define a custom data type, like `T` as in this answer.